# SignalR and connect excessive response

Tags: performance, signalr, azure-application-insights

I am using SignalR for three calls, all very basic, and I have just attached Application Insights to the website to monitor the performance.

For some reason, I am getting very high average duration for signalR/connect

GET /mysite/signalr/connect  3.58 minutes (average duration)

Anyone have any idea what is causing this or how I can drill into the metrics to find out what is happening.

As far as the application is going, it is working fine from an end users perspective with no issues.

Answer (score -2):

Averages can be deceptive. You can try getting percentiles by going to analytics by clicking "Analytics" button on your applicationinsights overview page on Azure portal. And run a query like -
requests 
 | where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
 | summarize percentiles(duration, 50, 90, 95) by bin(timestamp, 1h)

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree with averages, 99th percentile is 26 minutes for this call....!, my main concern is the SignalR issue taking so long